# What's the while() replacement in rxjs 5 ？

Tags: javascript, rxjs, observable

From [here](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/while.md) there should be a `while()` function that repeat the observable base on condition, however from the latest rxjs source code, it apparently this `while()` function was removed. So what's the replacement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want [`repeatWhen`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-repeatWhen), from the docs:

> Returns an Observable that mirrors the source Observable with the exception of a complete. If the source Observable calls complete, this method will emit to the Observable returned from notifier. If that Observable calls complete or error, then this method will call complete or error on the child subscription. Otherwise this method will resubscribe to the source Observable.

Usage for something like `while` would be something like this:

```
// Continues to resubscribe so long as the condition function returns true.
source.repeatWhen(
  notifiers => notifiers.takeWhile(_ => condition())
);
```

Hint: The reactivex.io/rxjs page has a decision tree widget that is extremely helpful in finding an operator to fit your needs.

Comment: yes that's it, little confusion that there are many doc site available now, but not updated to the latest rxjs 5 code, having to check the source code sometimes.